# random forest regression for multiple outputs (or tasks)

Tags: regression, random-forest

i have a multi-output regression problem with d_x input features and d_y outputs.  the outputs have a complex, non-linear correlation structure.

i'd like to use random forests to do the regression.  as far as i can tell, random forests for regression only work with a single output, so i would have to train d_y random forests - one for each output.  this ignores their correlations.

is there an extension to random forests that takes output correlations into account?  maybe something like [gaussian process regression for multi-task learning](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips20/NIPS2007_0431.pdf).

thanks.

Comment: here's the best i've found so far: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/tree.html#multi-output-problems

Comment: [Related question.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32880/1351)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the 'Multivariate Random forest'.